# Which probe sensor strength is necessary for low-sec exploration?

Tags: eve-online

I'm thinking about trying to do some low-sec exploration. I'll have to use an unbonused ship, as I won't get the necessary combat capabilities otherwise, and my scanning skills are rather mediocre.

Under these circumstances I suspect that the probe sensor strength might be problematic. So I'm wondering on how high the sensor strength has to be to be able to scan down all signatures that can appear in low-sec space?

Comment: Is using 2 different ships totally impossible? A rigged Covert Ops makes a very good scanning vessel, even with low scanning skills, but high Covert Ops skill. But in the end, you won't get around getting better skills, using Sister's stuff. I would also highly recommend a T3, since that is far more versatile even with scanning outfit and can also cloak. How much sensor strength you actually need, depends highly on the signature though. There is no formula for that afaik.

Comment: Just fyi, you can cloak while scanning. Deploy the probes, move away at least 2 km or let them warp off, then you can cloak up. Makes life in low or nullsec much easier while concentrating on your probes. Or, if you can, sit in front of a Starbase. Nobody will visit you there and if they do, the Starbase will make short work with them.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness One of the recent Odyssey patches has made scan probes no longer decloak you or prevent you from cloaking

Answer (score 2):

In the current scanning system all anomalies are divided into bands with each band having its own base signal strength. A list of bands and signal strengths is available on [this](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Complete_Signature_Strength_List) EVE wiki page.

The lowest base signal strength, and consequentially most difficult to scan down, anomalies have a base signal strength of 1.25%. Thus according to [this guide](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Signal_Strength) (and allowing for the skill changes in Odyssey) and assuming an 8-probe formation you need a probe sensor strength of at least 68.59 in order to be able to scan them down at all.

The easiest way to get to this level of scan strength on an unbonused ship is to have a combined total of at least 6 levels in Astrometrics and Astrometric Rangefinding, fit 2 gravity capacitor rigs to your ship and use sisters core scanner probes in a T1 core probe launcher.

Of course this is just the minimum level required to have any chance of completely scanning down any anomaly, better skills and equipment will give you more leeway with probe positioning and range, allowing you to scan faster.

Answer (score -1):

You will probably be able to scan most of them down with a standard Core Scanning Probe and Core Probe Launcher (I used to use the standard Tech 1 modules/charges when I first started living in WH's)

However I would recommend at least using `Sisters Core Scan Probes`, and if you can afford it (since it's low-sec, and the item costs approx 50-60m isk) use the `Sisters Core Probe Launcher` (not the extended launcher if you're on an unbonused ship).